# Simple PHP question about menu & content best practice

Tags: php, layout, hyperlink, include

OK, so for the first time I am building a full website and working with php. Now I encounter a problem:

Let'ss say my site is simply has a header with a menu and a area with content. Of course, I would like to have a header.php and several content files like content1.php content2.php and content3.php for example. This way you only have to change the menu in 1 file as you would understand.

How then is it best to build the site:

A. put something like this in every content file:

```
  <?php include 'header.php'; ?>

  here the content of the content page 1
```

B. make an index file with something like:

```
   <?php include 'header.php'; ?>

   <?php include 'content1.php'; ?>
```

how then is it done that when in the menu the link to content2.php is clicked the header is still on that page too?

C. something else? Maybe a good tutorial on how to make these kind of pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking to maximize the benefit of reusing code/elements, then you're on the right track with your second option:

> B. make an index file with something like:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'content1.php'; ?>
```

> how then is it done that when in the menu the link to content2.php is clicked the header is still on that page too?

**Here's how** (a simplistic example):

Route all of the similar requests (content1,2,3) through your `index.php` script using the query string - `mod_rewrite` can make this pretty. Then serve the main content section based on the request.

For example a link:

```
<a href='index.php?page=content1'>Content 1</a>
```

And detecting the content to serve:

```
<php
    $pages['content1'] = 'content1.php';
    $pages['content2'] = 'content2.php';

    $pages['default'] = $pages['content1']; //set default content

    $page = 'default';
    if(isset($pages[$_GET['page']]){
        $page = $pages[$_GET['page']]; //make sure the filename is clean
    }

?>
<?php include 'header.php'; //header here?>
<?php include $page; //correct content here?>
```

Not only is there a single place to change your header, but now there's a single place to change your entire layout.

Of course this is just a simplistic example, there are many PHP frameworks that do all this for you (using MVC).

Comment: oh and btw, what i always see these days is that site don't show their extensions anymore (it is also handy if i would change to some other filetype) so i'd like to ask: Isn't it easier to do that if i use this method, in that way i dont have to declare  $pages['content1'] = 'content1.php'; etc for every page. Then i could just say: if(isset($_GET['page']){
        $page = $_GET['page']; //or is this not clean than?
    }.

Comment: @Javaaaa You don't want to include a filename the user provides - then they could (conceivably) access any file they wanted by passing it as `?page=filename`. That's why my example referenced an array where the filenames are specified.

Answer (score 3):

Simple instead of a index.php including the content files, you do:

header.php:

```
 <a href="content1.php">content 1</a><br />
 <a href="content2.php">content 2</a><br />
```

content2.php:

```
<?php
    include('header.php');
?>

This is the page with 'content 1'
```

content2.php:

```
<?php
    include('header.php');
?>

This is the page with 'content 2'
```

Comment: thanks! But if i were to have 1000's of content pages, isn't there a way to do it differently? like it was 10 years ago with frames. Like make a link in the header only change a certain div of the page for example?

Comment: PHP does have "auto_prepend_file" and "auto_append_file" that you can set in PHP.ini, which you could use to automatically insert the header files. But this is problematic, as it's a "dumb" insertion - all files, regardless of how they work (e.g. this would break sessions and download scripts).

Comment: Changing a single div would require you have some javascript to make the changes, which is mostly out of PHP's hands.

Comment: Marc way is the best way, if having 100's of pages I'd go for writing a cms backend and just having one page that loads the content in.

Answer (score 2):

> But if i were to have 1000's of content pages, isn't there a way to do it differently? like it was 10 years ago with frames.

Short answer, no.  The quickest way for a small website would be to use the header method that @mark b describes.  Not only is it fast, but it also allows you to rely on URL paths which can be beneficial to SEO.

Long answer, maybe.  Frames have essentially been replaced by use of the dom, where one assigns content to a div and does an update.  It's fast, much easier to control than the old frames were, and can be done asynchronously (via AJAX)   However, it's also a lot more work to deal with than the old target= functionality.  Clients love it, but it does take time to code it.  Significant time, in fact, if you're dealing with a ton of pages and lots of content.

Another option would be to use a templating system like Zend Framework to build your views into a unified template for display.  But, it would add the overhead of a framework which can be sizable.

Finally, since you have PHP at your disposal, you could just pull all the content from the DB and essentially run the entire site on one "page".  The URL string would contain a parameter that tells it what content to pull from the DB and replace in your generic "getter" page.  A true CMS system of sorts.

Good luck.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted you, but i really learned a lot from your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Option A reduces your number of files, though as you're getting more and more complex in your site design, you may want to look at [Smarty](http://smarty.net), as that completely separates the "view" from the "data" of the page. Plus it's very robust and established as a framework.

Answer (score -1):

You could use phps __autoload().  It sounds kind of dirty, but but class wrappers around your content, then a single accessor at the end of each file.

Each file would look something like:

```
class header
{
  public static function getContent() {
    //return your content
}

header::getContent();
```